# Availability of handles presented in MONITORENUMPROC callback of EnumDisplayMonitors

Tags: winapi, gdi

The `MONITORENUMPROC` callback function of `EnumDisplayMonitors` gives me two handles. One of the type `HMONITOR` and one `HDC`.

- `HMONITOR` should reference the monitor.
- `HDC` is the handle to the device context of that monitor.

Do I need to release any of those handles before returning from the callback function? If not, how long will they stay around? May I save them for later use?

Comment: So I still can use those handles when `EnumDisplayMonitors` has finished or not?

Comment: You may save them for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to release any of those handles before returning from the
> callback function?

No, unless it is explicitly stated in the document to release, like the [`GetWindowDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc#remarks) function: **After painting is complete, the [`ReleaseDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc) function must be called to release the device context.**

> May I save them for later use?

Generally speaking, yes. A physical display has the same `HMONITOR` as long as it is part of the desktop. When a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message is sent, any monitor may be removed from the desktop and thus its `HMONITOR` becomes invalid or has its settings changed. Therefore, an application should check whether all `HMONITOR` are valid when this message is sent.

`HDC` handle is from the `EnumDisplayMonitors`, and its life cycle depends on the `HDC` parameter in `EnumDisplayMonitors`.